# how to fix a kindle paperwhite repair code 2?

Tags: kindle-paperwhite

how to fix a kindle paperwhite repair code 2 when the restarting is not working, and the laptop does not recognice the kindle as a device?

I've tried the 40 seconds restart, and not working, and I can't use the note for thee root directory, because the laptop does not recognice the kindle as a device